# Magento2 : Custom Place Order

Tags: magento2

I  have created custom place order action, below:

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form', 
    'jquery', 
    'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/iframe'        
],
function ($, Component, setPaymentInformationAction, additionalValidators, fullScreenLoader) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'VendorName_SampleModule/payment/method'
        },

        getCode: function() {
            return 'vendorname_samplemodule';
        },

        isActive: function() {
            return true;
        },

        validate: function() {
            var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
            return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
        },
        /**
         * Prepare and process payment information
         */
        preparePayment: function () {



          var card = function(){
            return {
              'card_number'     : $("#vendorname_samplemodule_cc_number").val(),
              'card_exp_month'  : $("#vendorname_samplemodule_expiration").val(),
              'card_exp_year'   : $("#vendorname_samplemodule_expiration_yr").val(),
              'card_cvv'        : $("#vendorname_samplemodule_cc_cid").val(),

              // Set 'secure', and 'gross_amount', if the merchant wants transaction to be processed with 3D Secure
              'secure'       : false,
              //'gross_amount'   : $("#price").val()
              'gross_amount'   : 10000
            }
          };


          Veritrans.token(card, callback);


          function callback(response) {
                if (response.status_code == '200') {

                     $("#vendorname_samplemodule_token_id").val(response.token_id);
                    // $("#vendorname_samplemodule-form").submit();  <-- not working
                    // PlaceOrder();

                } else {

                    console.log('Error');
                }
              }


        }
    });
}
);
```

If response code 200, PlaceOrder() function triggered.  I have no idea how to trigger Placeorder()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your js component extends `Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form`, which extends `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default`.

The `default` js component contains implementation of `placeOrder` function, so in your component you just need to call it:

```
var self = this;
function callback(response) {
    if (response.status_code == 200) {
        $("#vendorname_samplemodule_token_id").val(response.token_id);
        self.placeOrder();
    } else {
        console.log('Error');
    }
}
```

Also you need override `getData` function to set correct request data.

For more details please check [the official dev guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html) how to add a custom payment method. Also, you can use [sample-module-payment-gateway](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) as an example for custom payment integrations or [payments methods](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html) documentation.